# In 7 Wonders, can you make an informed decision on which resources to draft?

Tags: 7-wonders

I am learning 7 Wonders from the rulebook but I do not see this question addressed. Is there a way to know which structures you can build by taking a specific resource other than memorizing the cost of each structure?

For example, let's say I am passed a manufactured goods card such as glass and I already can produce two wood and clay. Is there a way for me to tell which structures are opened up for me if I take that glass without memorizing which structures in the game require glass and some subset of two wood and clay?

Comment: I've got this as a comment and not an answer as 'pages of rule book' covers it.  What I would do is try and focus on resources your neighbour don't have  or you cant buy from them later.  That way, with good financial management, all cards will be available to you without needing to memorise them them all.   The only card I've got memorised in the Age II School costing 1 wood and 1 scroll as the School science symbol is only one which chains to the other two symbols.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last pages in the rulebook have a tree showing all the structures, what they cost, when they become available, and which structures allow them to be built for free. I'm not aware of something similar for the expansions though.

That being said, if you're constantly analyzing all the cards that might become available in the future before making a pick, you're not going to be very popular with your group...